# App crash at time image save in Photos on iPhone5 but works fine in rest devices

Tags: ios, info-plist

In app i try to save image to photos using following line

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imgForData, nil, nil, nil);
```

For that i already add

```
Privacy - Photo Library Additions Usage Description
```

in info.plist file

I am using xcode 9 for development
But it crash when run in iphone 5 with ios 10.3
Error says add `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` in info.plist

in other device like 6s,7, 5s with ios 10.3 and ios 11 works perfect.

if i add `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` instead `NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription` than it will work for iphone 5 but it will stop working for rest devices

please suggest which key i should use `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` or `NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription`

I simply want save image to photo library

Comment: try both keys...!

Comment: Yes,for simulator it works. Will see it will work on device or not i have not device. thanks for comment @Lion

Answer (score 2):

It's because -

`NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription` - available iOS 11 and above

`NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` - available iOS 6 and above

When you try to run on iPhone 5 with iOS 10, the first one is not found, which is why it crashes.

Check [Cocoa keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html) and their availability.

As Lion recommend - you can add both keys.